# Should the tag for the Zoom video conferencing app be [zoom] or [zoom-meeting] or something else?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over on Ask Ubuntu, we had [a discussion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19467/158442) somewhat recently due to the  frequent mistagging of `zoom` (for the functionality of zooming in/out) vs `zoom-meeting` (our tag for the Zoom video conferencing app).

And now a new [zoom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom) is rearing its head here as well, so, given AU's experience, I wonder if we should nip that problem in the bud by using a clearer tag name for the video conferencing app right from the start. I suggest [zoom-meeting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) like on AU, but I'd welcome anything that's clearer than [zoom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom).

Comment: Is it expected to have tags for each piece of video conferencing software, or should we just have a `video-conferencing` tag? I'm not sure we have any other _specific_ video conferencing software tags.

Comment: There's [tag:jitsi-meet], and I suppose [tag:microsoft-teams] and [tag:Skype] could also be included in that group

Comment: The Zoom software does have the trouble of sharing its name with a common technical verb. (A problem that we don't run into with "bash" or "boot", for examples; "find" hasn't been much trouble, either). Just as anecdata, it looks like the 4 existing [tag:zoom] Q's here are actually about the Zoom software. We have a bit over [200 questions with the term "zoom"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=zoom%20-%5bzoom%5d%20is%3aQ) used functionally.

Comment: I've had a really quick scan through the questions for [tag:jitsi-meet], [tag:microsoft-teams], and [tag:skype]. Many of them appear to be application-specific and wouldn't be particularly well served by a generic tag (with or without synonyms for the common application names)

Comment: Just for additional data: [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14242/356789) uses [zoom-meeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting), Android.SE uses [zoom-cloud-meetings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom-cloud-meetings) (because it's the official name of the Android app), and [Apple.SE](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3990/95704) uses [zoom.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom.app)